# Let's get some free advertising for our site!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

For those of you who are avid Stack Exchange users you'll know that most graduated sites have a place for **free community advertising for stuff like open source software, other SE sites, and other stuff that the community is interested in.** Obviously we can't get it on our site since we are still in beta, but we could and *should* get some ads for our site.

They're refreshed every year, and they are just getting started up again so it's a great time to start. This post is to brainstorm where and what we want to advertise on the SE network. Feel free to add some sketches and ideas.

Answer (score 7):

### [Electrical Engineering.](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/community-promotion-ads-2015)

We have a similar scope to theirs, but we cover slightly different areas. This could be a great way to drive traffic to our site.

Edit: it seems like [someone has already done this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4066/18442). Cool!

Comment: I have seen several "migrated rom Electrical Engineering" I believe that it is a good site to advertise on

Answer (score 1):

[Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) 
Quite a number of Arduino related questions are already being asked there, so there is a lot of overlap in scope.

Comment: That isn't a graduated site yet, otherwise it would be a great candidate.

Answer (score 0):

What if we created more of an application based photo.  When I need to wire, I go to Electrical Engineering, when I need to work on motor control and algorithms I check Robotics, and when I need to program I use stack overflow and sometimes Arduino.

I mainly think of Arduino as a site which helps in applying the Arduino to specific applications.  Does that make sense?

We could feature some type of cool hack or apparatus that someone has built.  Or a meme of an Arduino controlled project that gets people interested.